# Can we see the Fourier transform as a filtering operation?

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, linear-systems

Is the Fourier Transform (FT) a filtering operation?
Is it possible to graphically represent this transform?
I know that a signal can be represented in the frequency domain, but I want to know if the FT operation can be "drawn" as a coefficient series.

The FT matrix is composed by $N\times N$ elements, and I can apply it to the input sequence of length $N$ in order to obtain an output sequence of length $N$. But I want to understand if there is another way to see the FT matrix in one dimension.

Comment: What do you mean by "drawed" as a coefficient series ?

Comment: A very similar question has been asked before. You can interpret the FFT as [an equally-spaced bank of complex-valued critically-sampled bandpass filters](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16060/filter-banks-and-fft-are-they-similar-conceptually/16087#16087). This is equivalent to thinking of the FFT as a bank of filters, each of which having an impulse response of the form $e^{j\omega_k n}$, where $\omega_k$ is the center frequency of the $k$-th bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fourier transform is linear. In its discrete version, its result can be interpreted as the result of $N$ different (complex) filters (whose impulse responses are sines with different frequencies) run in parallel, whose outputs are subsampled by a factor of $N$. In other words, a critically sampled complex filter bank.

If you think of a traditional linear filter, that weights samples of a signal, then you cannot really interpret an FT as a "single" filter.

It is possible to graphically represent this transform for 1D signals, using spiral-like or phasor representations to express their phase, as depicted in [What is the physical significance of negative frequencies?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/431/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-negative-frequencies):

[image: phasor-like complex representation]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The DFT matrix only contains powers of a complex root of unit. Every row or column holds increasing powers of a common power ($\omega^{mn}=(\omega^m)^n$); hence the real and imaginary parts follow (co)sinusoids of increasing frequencies.

https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/DFT_Sinusoids.html

Every component of the DFT of a signal is a convolution of the signal with those sinusoids.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a (continuous infinite) FT/Fourier Transform.

But finite length DFT or FFT operation is equivalent to the parallel application of a bunch of overlapping (mediocre to bad) complex FIR filters, each with a frequency response that looks like a Sinc function.  The Sinc filter response is due to the (implied default) rectangular window applied to either the sample data, or the FIR filter's impulse response, or both (of length N) during the application of any DFT or FFT.

(For non band-limited input, the response is actually a Direchlet kernel or periodic Sinc.)